# UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData does not show image after pdf creation

Tags: ios, swift, uiprintpagerenderer

I am working on the `HtmltoPDF` creation. It is working fine when some image URL but not working with my server image URL.

[Working URL downloaded from the google](https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260) 
[image]

[Issue in the server image URL](https://testpie.azurewebsites.net/MobileData/Attachment/ef480330-cdbb-4d05-b700-4efecce2d2d0)

[image]

I have put here my code for the pdf generation. Please find it

```
func exportHTMLContentToPDF(HTMLContent: String) -> String {
        let printPageRenderer = IPPrintPageRenderer()

        let printFormatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: HTMLContent)
        printPageRenderer.addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)

        let pdfData = drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer: printPageRenderer)
        let str = "\(Global.kretriveUserData().firstName!.firstCharacter!)\(Global.kretriveUserData().Name!.firstCharacter!)".uppercased()

        pdfFilename = "\(getDocDir())/\(str + invoiceNumber!).pdf"
        pdfData?.write(toFile: pdfFilename, atomically: true)

        print(pdfFilename)
        return pdfFilename
    }


    func drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer) -> NSData! {
        let data = NSMutableData()

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRect.zero, nil)
        for i in 0..<printPageRenderer.numberOfPages {
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
            printPageRenderer.drawPage(at: i, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())
        }
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        return data
    }

    func getDocDir() -> String {
        return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    }
```

You can find a full demo [here](https://github.com/appcoda/Print2PDF).

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a pdf from a webView you need to prepare your HTML code, create the WebView and inject the HTML code inside the webView and in webView `didFinishLoading` print the HTML content inside the pdf using the same width and height of the webView.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(webView.viewPrintFormatter(), startingAtPageAt: 0);


    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: webView.frame.size.width, height: webView.frame.size.height) // take the size of the webView
    let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    // 4. Create PDF context and draw
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)
    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
    }
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

    print(documentsPath)

    pdfData.write(toFile: "\(documentsPath)/pdfName.pdf", atomically: true)

    self.pdfPath = "\(documentsPath)/pdfName.pdf"
    self.pdfTitle = "pdfName"
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPDFSegue", sender: nil)
    webView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.loadingScreenViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Happy coding:)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Works great! After waiting for it to load, the print formatter has all the data, the html and image data!